# Not breaking out of loop

Tags: python-3.x

Relative newbie to Python here. My program at this point is waiting for the user to press enter so it can get back to the main loop. Is something wrong with the following code? (Ignore the print statements, I am using them for debugging.)

```
def checkReturnKeyPress():
    print ('check return key function started')
    while True:  # loop until user presses return key
        print ('check return key 2nd loop')
        for event in pygame.event.get():  # event handling loop
            print ('keydown for loop')
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                print ('keydown')
                if event.key == K_RETURN:
                    print ('return')
                    return
```

Sorry again for how messy this is, I'll clean it up once it's working. I have a feeling the part that's wrong is the "for event in pygame" part, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `break` in there somewhere. I'm guessing the `K_RETURN` is where you are looking for the return key to be pressed. If so you should add a `break` after the print('return') so that you will break out of your infinite loop.

Comment: The problem is it's never reaching that point. The console is just printing "check return key 2nd loop over and over". The problem has to be earlier than that.

Comment: What happens if you print(event) in your for loop?

Comment: In that case does pygame.event.get() return anything ?

Comment: Not at the moment.

Comment: I think that is your problem, if your for loop doesn't have an something to iterate over, it will not execute the following code. for dumb example: 
`lis = []`
`for item in lis:`
    `print ('something')`
something will never print